# Putting an anti-symmetric matrix into standard form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an anti-symmetric real square matrix of even dimension. Thus:

- $A \in M_{2N}(\mathbb{R})$
- $A + A^{T} = 0$

Is it possible to find a real, square matrix $D$ of the same dimension such that (and, hopefully $D^{T} = kD^{-1}$ for some $k$ so a change of coordinates by rotation):

$$D^{T}AD = \Sigma_{-\pi/2}$$

Where $\Sigma_{-\pi/2}$ is the matrix of the transformation that affects the standard basis $\{e_1, e_2, \ldots e_{2N} \}$ as follows:

$$\Sigma_{-\pi/2} : e_i \mapsto -e_{i+1} \text{ and } e_{i+1} \mapsto e_i \text{ where } i \equiv 1 (2)$$

So it rotates every consecutive pair of axes by $\pi/2$ clockwise. It looks like a matrix whose diagonal entries are $2\times 2$ submatrices of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

The case $N=1$ is true:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}0 & x \\ -x & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \sqrt{x} \\ -\sqrt{x} & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & -\sqrt{x} \\ \sqrt{x} & 0\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Comment: The answer is yes!  It is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general. However, if we are willing to drop the (scaled) unitary assumption, then it is possible.

First notice that given a skew-symmetric, even dimensional matrix $A$ that looks like:

$$
A: = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & a_{12} &\ldots & a_{12n} \\
-a_{12} & 0 & a_{23} &\ldots & a_{22n} \\
\vdots \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Because of the (skew) symmetry, we can perform a sequence of *pairs* of row and column operations, where the column operation is similar to the row operation in that the same type of operation is applied to columns, or in other words conjugation with an elementary matrix and its transpose such that the first two rows and columns look like:

$$
EAE^T = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & &  \ast \\
\vdots & 0 & & \ast \\
0 & 0 & & \ast \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then, the result follows from induction.

Answer (score 0):

It sure is!  One way to prove this is using the spectral theorem (either the version for real matrices or normal matrices):

Any skew-symmetric matrix $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable since $iA$ is Hermitian (and moreover, $A$ has imaginary eigenvalues).  We may select a corresponding "scaled rotation" matrix with the same eigenvalues.  Since the two transformations are unitarily diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues, the two transformations are unitarily similar.  Since these two real transformations are unitarily similar, they are necessarily orthogonally similar, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Hi. Can you expand your answer a little bit. I'm having trouble seeing why a general skew-symmetric matrix has the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @stnx well, I'm not really sure where to start.  My answer, as it is, provides a full answer, but requires that you know what I'm talking about.  In any case, here's an attempt: one way to see that the eigenvalues of a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ are imaginary is to note that $A^2 = -A^TA$ is symmetric with negative eigenvalues.  Similarly, your $2 \times 2$ "rotation matrices" clearly satisfy $\Sigma^2 = -\mu^2 I$ for some $\mu \geq 0$.

Comment: Nice try passing off your incomplete answer to my 'not understanding' elementary linear algebra

Comment: @sntx That was not what I was trying to say, and I'm offended to hear you say that I'm "passing my answer off" as anything.  The results that I use are not what I would call "elementary linear algebra"; even the spectral theorem is something that might not qualify as "elementary".  My point was that I use a lot of "advanced" tools, and it's hard for me to know what exactly needs explanation here.  I did address your direct question, namely: how might you see that the eigenvalues of skew symmetric matrices match those of your scaled $\pi/2$ rotations.

Comment: I know that the eigenvalues of a skew-symm matrix are complex, but it is not true that they are the same or a multiple of those of $\Sigma_{-\pi/2}$,  i.e $\pm i$

Comment: It is true, though.  Skew-symmetic have purely imaginary eigenvalues (in the sense that those eigenvalues are some real number times $i$).

Comment: They are purely imaginary follows from the spectral theorem, what does not follow is that they are all $\pm ki$ for some $k$

Comment: Are you trying to say that we might have a skew-symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues don't come in conjugate pairs?

Comment: Of course not, I'm saying all the conjugate pairs are different.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were allowing for $\Sigma$ to have a form such as
$$
\Sigma = 
\pmatrix{
0&2\\-2&0\\&&0&-3\\&&-3&0
}
$$
which would allow for that